# Using LINQ in an Update Method - trouble with where clause

Tags: c#, linq, where-clause

I'm writing an update method that passes in a list of objects to be updated, I'm wondering how I would write a LINQ query to grab all the objects from the database that need to be updated

This is an example of my update method with the linq query that I'm trying to make (pseudo-code used for the part I don't know how to do)

```
void UpdateObjects(List<MyObjects> updatedObjects)
{

    DatabaseContext myContext = new DatabaseContext();

    var originalObjectsThatRequireUpdating = from o in myContext.MyObjects
                                             where o.ID matches one of updatedObjects.ID
                                             select o;


    foreach (var originalObject in originalObjectsThatRequireUpdating )
    {
         IEnumerable<MyObjects> tmpItem = updatedObjects.Where(i => i.ID == originalObject.ID);

         originalObject.Field1 = tmpItem.ToList()[0].Field1;
         //copy rest of the fields like this
    }

    myContext.SubmitChanges();

}
```

I don't know how to create a linq query easily with something like

```
 where o.ID matches one of updatedObjects.ID
```

also if someone knows an easier way to accomplish what I'm doing please tell, this seems sort of like an odd way to do it, but was the only way I can think of / know how to do at this point.

Comment: How do you establish `updatedObjects` ? Normally the EF tracks changes, all you would need is a context.SaveChanges().

Comment: @HenkHolterman - This method is part of a webservice, the `updatedObjects` is coming from a silverlight application, I don't know enough about how EF tracks the changes to get that working, but I'm assuming that doesn't work here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do that with:

```
where updatedObjects.Any(uo => uo.ID == o.ID)
```

Comment: This is more compact than my answer; I'd forgotten about IEnumerable.Any :P

Comment: Using Any raises the `Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementation of query operators except the Contains() operator` exception

Comment: You can try updatedObjects.Select(uo => up.Id).Contains(o.Id)

Answer (score 0):

You should be looking to implement **batch updates** with linq for example like it's described at http://www.aneyfamily.com/terryandann/post/2008/04/Batch-Updates-and-Deletes-with-LINQ-to-SQL.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could create a lambda or another method that performs the check for you; for example

```
where IDMatches(o.ID, updatedObjects)
```

and then define IDMatches as a simple iteration over updatedObjects.

```
static void IDMatches(int id, List<MyObject> updatedObjects)
{
    foreach (MyObject updated in updatedObjects)
    {
        if (id == updated.ID)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```